# General Alkaloid Extraction Process

Tags: organic-chemistry, extraction, drugs, medicinal-chemistry, alkaloids

I'm getting into alkaloid extraction from various ethnobotanicals. It is a bit frustrating trying to extract alkaloids from ethnobotanicals without good guides out there, and I wanted to make my own techniques and experiments. However, I need to know what the basic outline is for extraction. Are there any guides or basic principles I need to know?

I'm interested in extracting for example Leonurine from Wild Dagga or Mitragyna and 7-OH-Mitragyna from Kratom.

---

What I was looking for was Acid-Base or Liquid-Liquid extractions.

Comment: Your question appears to be a little broad as written. Can you provide a narrower scope (such as the alkaloids you're interested in)? Also, what is "teks"?

Comment: Tek is short for techniques in various forums. I'm interested in extracting for example Leonurine from Wild Dagga or Mitragyna and 7-OH-Mitragyna from Kratom. I know there are several steps people use such as modifying the pH, defatting using different solvents, etc.

Answer (score 6):

#### 7-Hydroxymitragynine

The extraction and crystallization of the parent alkaloid, **mitragynine**, from dried leaves of *Mitragyna speciosa* (Kratom), has been described in great detail by *A. H. Beckett, E. J. Shellard* and *A. N. Tackie* in *Planta Med.*, **1965**, *13*, 241-246 ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1055/s-0028-1100118)).

(Interestingly, the procedure also furnished **speciofoline**, a spiroindolo indolizidine alkaloid.)

#### Leonurine

A first extraction was seeming reported by *S. Kubota* and *S. Nakajima* in *Nippon Yakubutsuqaku Zasshi*, **1930**, 153. I don't have a DOI and the source is most likely in Japanese.

I don't have personal experience with the extraction of guanidines from biological material and would probably rather try to synthesize **leonurine**, following the procedures described in *Tetrahedron*, **1969**, *25*, 5155-5161 ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0040-4020(69)80036-0)).

---

#### General guidelines

I have given some hints on extraction in an answer to a question on the use of [TLC in alkaloid identification](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/63620/how-do-i-perform-thin-layer-chromatography-to-identify-alkaloid-content-in-fruit/63634#63634).